# Testing Multiple useState hooks onClick With Jest, useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

How would I test the following functionality using Jest & Enzyme?

```
const TheComponent = () => {
  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState('');
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState('0px');

  const content = useRef(null);

  const toggleExpand = () => {
    setActiveState(setActive === '' ? 'active' : '');
    setHeighState(setActive === 'active' ? '0px' : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={content} style={{maxHeight: `${setHeight}`}}>
      </div>
      <button onClick={toggleExpand}>
        <span className={`text ${setActive === 'active' ? 'active' : 'disabled'} `}>Collapse</span>
        <span className={`text ${setActive === '' ? 'active' : 'disabled'} `}>Expand</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What's throwing me off is calling both setActiveState and setHeightState on toggleExpand onClick, and I'm also not sure how to pass in or mock content.current.scrollHeight

Answer (score 3):

Inside the test block

`React.useState = jest.fn(`)

Make the mock return an array that can be destructured the same way useState return value is destructured,

```
React.useState
.mockReturnValueOnce([true, () => console.log("setState")])
.mockReturnValueOnce(["5ft", () => console.log("setHeight")]);
```

chaining the mockReturnValueOnce will return the first when the first call to useState is made and the second and when the second call to useState is made.

Comment: Error: Uncaught [TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))]

Comment: My code is 

const setUserSelectedAddressIndex = jest.fn();
    const setOriginalAddressList = jest.fn();
    React.useState
      .mockReturnValueOnce([0, setUserSelectedAddressIndex])
      .mockReturnValueOnce([originalAddressList, setOriginalAddressList]);

gives me error _react.default.useState.mockReturnValueOnce is not a function